# Bind an event on animation

Tags: jquery, event-handling, jquery-animate

I have a couple of elements that are being animated on a arrow click. 
Now I want that if they are being animated, to call an event. 
The thing is, they are all being animated in different ways, so I would have to 
fire this event on each element separately.

Is there a way to do something like `$('div:animated').live(...)` or something 
that would fire an event on the animated elements?

Comment: doesn't this work ? http://api.jquery.com/animated-selector/

Comment: this would fire only one time, I need to bind something every time an animation occurs

Comment: You could create a trigger you'd call every time you run `animate()`

Comment: Is that a common event that trigger the animations? If yes, just trigger a "runanimation" event or something there.

Comment: I want the elements that are being animated to change size according to their positions, however I don't want to write it on every separate element animation, I was hoping I could capture the event of animation and while it is running, to change their sizes according to their positions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$("div").animate({
    "top":20
},1000,function(){
    callback();
});

function callback(){
    //stuff here
}
```

or

```
$("#layer1, #layerMask").animate({
    "top":10
},{
    queue:false,
    duration:1000, 
    easing:"easing method if required", 
    complete:function(){
    callbacks();
    }   
});

function callback(){
    //stuff here
}
```

best way!
just use the call back every time you animate an element.

the only other ways i can think of are things like setInterval and check the element top value for change etc. but this would be messy and not advised.

Just take the hit and use callbacks. best practice.

Unless anyone else has any ideas.